# What power supply can I use for 2 servos?

Tags: pi-4, power, power-supply, connection, alternative-power

I am a complete noob when it comes to raspberry. I have 2 servos MG996R that I need to power from an external power supply. Currently I am doing it from the board, and when I turn both of them the board just shuts down.

I would really appreciate if you can suggest me a power suply that plugs in to a wall (as opposed to battery-one) and please feel free to explain how to do it as if I am 5-years old. I really have no idea how to connect anything.

Also feel free to post amazon/ebay links to power supplies. The servos I am using are these: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Diymore-Digital-Helicopter-Airplane-controls/dp/B07DQFXDC9/ref=sr_1_5?dchild=1&keywords=servos&qid=1614800439&sr=8-5

The raspberry model is 4-B.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a Raspberry Pi servo hat if you're just starting out and want to learn how to use servos.

There are a lot of them on the market but I'd go with something from Adafruit as they have a lot of very nice tutorials to go along with their products.

https://www.adafruit.com/product/2327

On that page they also link to an article on external power supply's to be used with the hat.

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-16-channel-pwm-servo-hat-for-raspberry-pi/powering-servos

EDIT:

To connect a servo via a breadboard and an external power supply you can have a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LwEBB6v559I

Adafruit also has a tutorial on this: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-8-using-a-servo-motor

Both uses batteries (I know you don't want to use batteries) but it will show you how to connect things. You can always swop out the battery pack for a power supply.

As for a power supply that you can use, Adafruit recommends this for up to 4 servos: https://www.adafruit.com/product/276

The specification that you're looking for is 5V 2A.

Perhaps these Amazon links will help:

[https://www.amazon.com/Universal-Adapter-5V-Power-Connector/dp/B0789PJR62/ref=sr_1_10?crid=X9QWFDLSR1I8&dchild=1&keywords=5v+2a+5.5mm&qid=1614816805&sprefix=5v+2a+5.5%2Caps%2C386&sr=8-10](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0789PJR62)

[https://www.amazon.com/DAYKIT-Female-2-1x5-5MM-Adapter-Connector/dp/B01J1WZENK/ref=sr_1_5?crid=Y62EQWCBQA9P&dchild=1&keywords=5.5mm+barrel+connector&qid=1614816875&sprefix=5.5mm+bar%2Caps%2C387&sr=8-5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01J1WZENK)

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply! I already have the servos, I have left an amazon link to them in my original post. I've checked the link you have provided but I think this is more complicated than what I want to achieve and I am getting a bit lost. I only need to make sure they are properly powered on and need help with what power supply to buy and how to connect the wires. I understand these hats might be helpful, but I don't have one available to me right now and I am sure there must be another way.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hopefully that help.